# How to binding fontsize from combobox to datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, datagrid

How to bindings values with fontsize from combobox to datagrid? I tried it but it didnt work

```
  <ComboBox Name="FontSizeComboBox" IsEditable="True" 
        Width="60" SelectedIndex="1"
                  Foreground="White">
            <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type System:Int32}">
                    <System:Int32>12</System:Int32>
                    <System:Int32>14</System:Int32>
                    <System:Int32>16</System:Int32>
                    <System:Int32>18</System:Int32>
                    <System:Int32>20</System:Int32>
                    <System:Int32>22</System:Int32>
                    <System:Int32>24</System:Int32>
                    <System:Int32>26</System:Int32>
                    <System:Int32>28</System:Int32>
                </x:Array>
            </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        </ComboBox>
   <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="dgrPoints" ItemsSource="{Binding Stations}" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True"
              FontSize="{Binding  Path=SelectedIndex.Value ,ElementName=FontSizeComboBox}" CellEditEnding="dgrPoints_CellEditEnding">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FontSize="{Binding Text, ElementName=FontSizeComboBox}"
```

`SelectedIndex` is, as the name suggests, an integer. It has no `Value` property. That's the index of the item the user selects. If the user selects the fourth item, it'll be the integer value `3`.

Ordinarily, I'd say this:

```
FontSize="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=FontSizeComboBox}"
```

...but your `ComboBox` ias `IsEditable="True"`, so you want `Text` instead. `SelectedValue` can only have a value that's found in the list, but `Text` can be anything the user types in.

Also, if you were binding to `SelectedValue`, you'd also need to change your font size item type to `double`, because a binding on the `FontSize` property can automatically convert from a string, but not from `Int32` (and `ComboBox.Text` is a string, of course):

```
<ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    <x:Array Type="{x:Type System:Double}">
        <System:Double>12</System:Double>
        <System:Double>14</System:Double>
        <System:Double>16</System:Double>
        <System:Double>18</System:Double>
        <System:Double>20</System:Double>
        <System:Double>22</System:Double>
        <System:Double>24</System:Double>
        <System:Double>26</System:Double>
        <System:Double>28</System:Double>
    </x:Array>
</ComboBox.ItemsSource>
```

Comment: thank you! it's working! And how to do that if I am changing size by clipboard in combobox it bindging with datagrid?

Comment: @Mr.DonKiHot Whoops, my bad. Updated my answer.